# How to force an user to save?

Tags: asp.net, events, drop-down-menu, selectionchanged

I have the following situation:
I coded a aspx app c#, the user has 4 dropdownlists, one textbox and two buttons (cancel, save) in a page. I need the user to be remembered to save any changes to the textbox before allowing him to change the index of any dropdownlist. So, if the user changes the textbox value, he only have the option to cancel or save those chhanges. If he tries to do something else, like changing the index of a dropdownlist, I need to cancel this event and give him a message to save or cancel before do this.

I've tried many ways, but they all seem amatours to me and give lots of colateral efects. Is there any decent/elegant way to do this?

Comment: I gave an answer below but I am really curious as to what you you are trying to achieve, because this has a bad smell; whatever the business logic is, I'll bet there's a simpler way...

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom validator for the TextBox. In the DropDownList's SelectedIndexChanged event handlers check the status of the TextBox and set the validator's args.IsValid property appropriately - you can notify the user via the TextBox CustomValidator ErrorMessage property to click Save if the value of the TextBox has changed.